# How to achieve Economic Order Quantity in inventory

Tags: postgresql, psql

Hope you are doing well.  I have a existing schema which maintains product batch and expiry date record and it sale short expiry products accordingly. Here is my existing schema
[image]

I am also tracking the batch which it sold in core_product_stock_sale. Now i am want to implement  Economic Order Quantity feature for my inventory system.

> is it possible with my existing database schema ?
>
> If it is not then please suggest me appropriate schema ?

Comment: What is Economic Order Quantity ?  If there is a formula, please edit your post to show it.  Also, please post sample data and result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.